# Why is there a difference in performance between prefilter and then join vs directly join in spark

Tags: apache-spark

In one of the spark conference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSplTjBKijU

The following code is listed as an optimization at 11:54

```scala
val medium_data_keys = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(medium.select("m_id").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect.toSeq)
val large_data_filtered = large.filter(col("large_id").isin(medium_data_keys.value: _*))
large_data_filtered.join(medium, large.col("large_id") === medium.col("m_id"))
```

Basically if you are joining a large data and medium data, the presenter say that filtering the large data by the medium data keys and then joining the table would be more efficient than joining the two table directly

What is the reasoning behind this? Is it because join involve the entire row (not just the key) ?

Answer (score 0):

To understand why this *could* (in function of the sizes of `large` and `medium`) be beneficial, you have to think about what a `join` operation really does.

In case `medium` is large enough not to easily be broadcasted to do a [broadcastHashJoin](https://blog.rockthejvm.com/spark-broadcast-joins/), both of your dataframes (`large` and `medium`) will be shuffled over to all executors. Shuffling is an expensive operation, because that means you have to send partitions of each dataframe over the network (which is slow).

With this approach, you're making `large` smaller (by filtering away the bits that won't be joined) **before** shuffling. That results in less data to have to be sent over the network and can be an optimization in some cases!